# Get cascade child K type in ts?

Tags: typescript

i am trying to get the child key with normal Cascade type.

```
type Cascade<C extends string, T extends Cascade<C, T>> = Partial<
  Record<C, T[]>
>

/**
 * {
 *   name: 'x',
 *   code: 'x',
 *   childGeoList: [{name: 'y', code: 'y'}]....
 * }
 */
interface AreaItem extends Cascade<'childGeoList', AreaItem> {
  name: string
  code: Number
}

type ChildKey = AreaItem extends Cascade<infer K, infer _> ? K : never

// ? why is A not 'childGeoList'
// fix it and let ChildKey equals 'childGeoList' ?
```

? why is A not 'childGeoList'

fix it and let ChildKey equals 'childGeoList' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately TS's inference abilities is unable to do this.  Without knowing in advance what `K` and `_` are, the type `Cascade<K, _>` seems to be too wide for the compiler to infer anything useful.

My suggestion here would be to do a more explicit computation of the key, like this:

```
type ChildKey<C extends Record<string, any>> =
    keyof { [K in keyof C as C[K] extends C[] | undefined ? K : never]: any };
```

Here you're just looking for any keys of `C` whose value is a possibly undefined array of `C`.  This works as desired for `AreaItem`:

```
type AreaItemChildKey = ChildKey<AreaItem>
// type AreaItemChildKey = "childGeoList"
```

It could possibly give surprising results if you have other properties which get in the way:

```
interface Oops extends Cascade<'x', Oops> {
    name: string;
    hello: Oops[]
}
type OopsChildKey = ChildKey<Oops>
// type OopsChildKey = "x" | "hello"
```

That might not be what you want but [structurally](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) that's the same as

```
interface Oops2 extends Cascade<'x' | 'hello', Oops2> {
    name: string;
}
type Oops2ChildKey = ChildKey<Oops2>
// type OopsChildKey = "x" | "hello"
```

so there's not much to be done there.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgZwMZwCYQDwyhAHsCAO1QSgWACcBLQgcwBooAVHfIk2RFdLRpgPn5QAvFAAKcCsCpwANhgCwAKCiqoAJQhIA9hVS9mAbQC6-ZWaXKaBCgDM4SaAEEKEOAEkCAW1YFipeGQ0TAByJAALKllUAHEIbQAZKnIQxhc3TwgvIQBvZTUoQjgvCAAuMkoaWny1HXRygDkAVy8AIwgKZQBfZWVQSFhI6IBpCBAsX3ZSTR09DHJqOkY4QhBBERrVAGsx7VsoHKhDYagaKB2QPdgoRFhj40n-O4eAHygm4ghbGghUKAB+KAncqECAANw6xnKKxAUC6AG5ekp+s5XB5vDAhqhRrDRJiotixhh0uishYAPTkqAoqAkzJefEjMYiKAAIgiBLiiWSwFZSOsHXsjigAHltGBSHg-BxAtxQrhUqLxQhcptCsUyhVFrRESo1OEILJZNpymKJSZun1wNAzQhGYTcYMCTiMLaKVSabb7TiWazcKyoG9WQajdo+ZYlAK7A4bcqAEyPGVcYIYEIKwNQEIh42K21x1V61RFErlBZVXU9ZHWpUSuPe5l4rEuvPu6nVr1Nhts-0Z4OG42soA)

Answer (score 0):

You could define the additional properties is an extenal type (e. g. `AreaItemExtension`) and [`Omit`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) (remove) them in the type comparison to help TypeScript inferring `"childGeoList"` correctly.

```
type Cascade<C extends string, T extends any> = Partial<
  Record<C, T[]>
>;

type AreaItemExtension = {
  name: string;
  code: number;
};

type AreaItem = Cascade<"childGeoList", any> & AreaItemExtension;

type ChildKey<T> = T extends Cascade<infer K, infer _> ? K : never;

type ChildKeyOfAreaItem = ChildKey<
  Omit<AreaItem, keyof AreaItemExtension>
>; // "childGeoList"
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgZwMZwCYQDwyhAHsCAO1QSgWACcBLQgcwBooAVHfIkqOQkAPigF4oABTgVgVOABsMAKChQAShCQB7CqiyMmAbQC6PGTwDcMmaEhQAghQhwAkgQC2AUTaEEVFYQFQA3nKhCOEcIAC4yShpaE3lVdHDCAFdHACMIChMAXxMzcGhrWwcIRx94ZDRMACIkAAsqSVQAcQgVABkqckrGLl4oADIrG3snVwJ3T0Ic82gYOoaAaQgQDCY+QRY8MY4ylHQMGgAzdKh5xkPjgH0+AH4TqASIADd0qbzYOdRFkAB5A4Lh4qlD5fWTyb6OKjADD-IqORgAayWKgOg0KIzcHi8BmMUAA9LioNUPs02h1gJUZEA)

Comment: The explanation is technically incorrect because excessive properties still allow you to assign one type to another https://tsplay.dev/WYKO2N

Comment: I agree that the reasoning here is incorrect.  Excess properties do not result in type incompatibility.  Could you fix it?